# Database Sync Problem

Tags: database, synchronization

The software my company puts on each of our customers' mobile computers has a local MySQL database. These mobile computers are connected to the internet via a mobile broadband card. We send information to be read into a string and stored in the customer's local database via XML files which range from 1kb to 600kb. (Note: We do this so customers will still have access to the data when an internet connection is unavailable.)

The 1-600kb XML files are stored in a folder for each user on our server until they are downloaded via a .net/C# webservice which serves up the file to the client which calls on the webservice with their token. Customers may have up to 20-40mb of these small XML files when they connect for the first time. In a normal day, they may download up to a few mb of these files. The software on the customer's mobile computer checks for files in their folder on the server every 10 seconds with a webservice.

A new XML file is made every 15 minutes with the changes which need to be made to the user's database, and no XML file is created if no changes are made. The largest XML file (600kb) has 1000 records for the user's local database. Each record has 10+ columns some with 10+ characters.

The problems with our method:

- This method is slow. (It can take 1 1/2 hours to get an empty database in sync.)
- There is no compression to the XML files, so download sizes are larger than necessary.
- The XML files are larger than they need to be because they contain unnecessary information.
- We are not keeping track of what's in the user's database, so users can become out of sync.
- It's file based, and this is causes lots of reads/writes on the hard disk.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like two problems to me.

1. Updating the user databases to the latest master database can be done by keeping track of versions. The user submits their version number when they call, and you return the SQL needed to update their version to the latest. Each time you update the master database, generate SQL to update from each possible previous version, then just return the appropriate SQL. I say SQL because that seems more efficient, but you can use XML or JSON or whatever and it would still be more efficient with versions.
2. Respecting user local changes is a more challenging problem. You could save the user changes as SQL or some other format off to the side, and re-apply them after the update. But who has the latest/best info is a difficult question. Often you need greater granularity than just user records. It's possible for one system to update part of the info - say a phone number for a contact - while the other system updates another part, say their email. If the system has to choose one contact entry or the other, either way you loose. To get it right you have to timestamp the changes to every field. If the remote devices are always online, you may have better luck attempting a sync and asking the user to resolve conflicts each time they want to make a change.